# MatTableDataSource: refresh table content after changing filterPredicate without changing filter

Tags: javascript, angular, mat-table

I am trying to dynamically change `filterPredicate` in `MatTableDataSource` to extend simple filtering.

- one constant condition - text filtering (value from search's text field) by two `string` columns
- additional, optional conditions for `Date` values activated by checkboxes - expiration date within one month, one week etc.).

When I mark checkboxes as checked, `filterPredicate` changes (optional condition is added properly), but the table content doesn't refresh until I change value in search's text field (`filter` value is changed).

Is there any way to force the table state to be updated?

Answer (score 0):

uses changedetectionref and method updateChangeSubscription()  of MatTableDataSource

```
...
constructor( private cd:ChangeDetectorRef ...) {        }
...
 refreshMethod(){
        this.dataSource._updateChangeSubscription();
        this.cd.markForCheck(); or this.cd.detectChanges(); 
    }
...
```

Comment: It fixed few cases, but only when dataSource.filter is not null or empty string.